# Dynamically assign value field for an apex:selectList

Tags: visualforce

I have created a custom component to represent selectLists. This allows them to be defined by a non-tech user to generate custom VF pages.

My question is can you dynamically set the value attribute for a select list? I have two fields in the controller. One for single selects that is of type string and one for multi selects that is of type List.

Problem is I can only set the value field to be one or the other. I want to be able to do something like the following. The formula field in the value attribute is invalid for the obvious reason
Component code:

```
<apex:attribute name="multiSelect"
     type="Boolean"
     assignTo="{!multiSelect}"
     required="true"
     description="Indicates if the drop down is multiSelect."
 />
 <apex:selectList id="selector"
     value="{!IF(multiSelect, multiValues, multiValue)}"
     multiselect="{!multiSelect}"
     size="3" 
     title="A title"
>
```

Controller code

```
public Boolean multiSelect { get; set; }
public List<String> multiValues { get; set; }
public String mulitValue { get; set; }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to dynamically choose which controller property you want to bind a VF component to, but with a bit of extra markup you can dictate which property is set:

```
<apex:attribute name="multiSelect"
    type="Boolean"
    assignTo="{!multiSelect}"
    required="true"
    description="Indicates if the drop down is multiSelect."
/>
<apex:selectList
    value="{!multiValues}"
    multiselect="true"
    rendered="{!multiSelect}"
>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectOpts}" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:selectList
    value="{!singleValue}
    multiselect="false"
    rendered="{!NOT(multiSelect)}"
>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectOpts}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Then determining which variable to use in the rest of your controller is as simple as checking the value of your `multiSelect` boolean.

Comment: Simple usually works best. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the `multiselect` possible selection values will be set when the page is loaded. It's not possible to 'dynamically' set them, however, it is possible to build up some logic to display a different set of values depending on some parameter passed into the component.

It maybe also possible to set them dynamically with javascript, or a partial refresh using an `<apex:actionFunction>` to change the values based on some arg. and re-render that component.

Comment: Yep the javascript work around is an option. I was just wondering if it was required as being able to choose the controller binding based on a formula or something like that would be helpful in this case.
Cheers for the response